# How to solve salesforce security issue (From Zap scanning report)

Tags: security

I am getting "  X-Frame-Options Header Not Set" issue in salesforce how I can solve this issue, I have attach a image please take a look on that image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that Salesforce abstract that from you by what they call the "Clickjacking protection", which deals with permission on how to frame your page. There's more info here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_clickjacking_enable.htm&language=en_US

I would suggest enabling it and running the ZAP scan again.

Answer (score 0):

See [Summer 15 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_vf_clickjack_with_headers_disabled.htm)

Clickjack protection secures your Visualforce pages against user interface redress attacks. You can enable clickjack protection for Visualforce pages that suppress the standard header. The setting is global to your organization and applies to all your Visualforce pages.

> To enable clickjack protection for Visualforce pages that suppress the
>   standard header, select **Enable clickjack protection for customer
>   Visualforce pages with headers disabled under Setup | Security
>   Controls | Session Settings.**
>
> Clickjack protection is implemented by adding a X-Frame-Options:
>   SAMEORIGIN header to Visualforce pages. **When headers are suppressed by
>   setting showHeader="false" on a page, this header isn’t added to the
>   page, and clickjack protection is disabled.**

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote this post.It's enough searched and provides a valuable information. Expecting from the downvoters to be brave and provide a thoughtful reason.I'd be glad to hear you.